# Resetting Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, reinstall

I'm having some trouble resetting my Windows 10 PC. Whenever I start the reset process, it always shows up an error message, saying "there was a problem resetting your PC".

Can anyone suggest as to what could be the source of the problem and how to overcome it.

Comment: Can you still log into Windows? Why are you trying to reset? Have you checked the Event Viewer?

Comment: Yes, I can log into Windows. The reason for reset is some bug which is causing me not to install any application due to UAC prompt nt showing up. I'm not sure how to check the event viewer.

Comment: Look it up: https://lmgtfy.com/?q=open+windows+10+event+viewer

Comment: Your two problems are likely related, but posting them as separate questions hides potentially relevant information on each question.  Merge this information into your other question and delete this one.

Answer (score 0):

DISCLAIMER: this will remove all your data

The easiest way to reset your PC if the built in reset is not working is to download a new/clean copy of the Windows image from https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10ISO using the Media Creation Tool. This tool can put the image on a USB drive which you can use to reinstall from. Once you have created the USB you need to reboot the machine by clicking on the restart button with the shift key held down. This will open up the boot menu and allow you to select your USB as the boot option. If this does not work then you need to enter the boot menu during a regular reboot and select your drive and reinstall as normal.

Comment: How will this method ensure that the new Windows installed will be registered with Microsoft, since my existing copy of Windows 10 is original. (Came pre-installed)

Comment: Also, will this method remove data in C drive only, or other drives too?