# Installing application on Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, windows-registry

I'm having some strange kind of trouble with Windows 10. Whenever I try to install any application, a **pop-up dialogue box is supposed to come**, asking for our confirmation, but **such a box doesn't appear**, and as a result, I'm unable to install any application.

Whenever I run an installation, **the screen dims,** but the dialogue box doesn't appear. The sound of the dialogue box does appear though. Can anyone help me with this kind of problem. What could be the reason for this and what are the possible solutions for the same.

Comment: You're talking about the UAC confirmation prompt? Have you checked your Event Viewer? Have you checked that your computer is fully up-to-date with security patches and updates? What build of Windows 10 are you running?

Comment: Also, is this the reason you're trying to refresh your Windows installation: https://superuser.com/questions/1304025/resetting-windows-10 If so, I have asked you several questions that need to be answered there to make your question answerable. It is generally not good to keep creating new questions. Instead, you should focus on one question, improving it until it gets answered.

Comment: Yes, I'm talking about the UAC prompt. My PC is upto date with the latest release of updates.

Comment: And yes, the reason for me posting the other question is same. I can neither install any application, nor refresh Windows 10.

Comment: Have you used the DISM repair commands: https://www.windowscentral.com/how-use-dism-command-line-utility-repair-windows-10-image

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a temporary solution to my problem. There is a way to bypass the UAC prompt, by creating a task using the 'Task Scheduler' feature of Windows. Here's the [link](http://www.thewindowsclub.com/create-elevated-shortcut-run-programs-bypass-uac) to the website I referred.

Basically, I was able to create a shortcut which would run my program with the highest administrative privileges, bypassing the UAC prompt. Will update the answer If I find a better solution.